# Can't run executable linked with libc

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, ld

I am assembling my hello world with the following command:

`nasm -f elf64 test.asm`

I then link with this:

`ld -s test.o -lc`

I know this works because `file a.out` shows me

`a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped`

However when i run this with `./a.out` i get `bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory`

When link without libc it runs fine! How can I get my libc linked exe to run?

Comment: [Linking Linux x86-64 assembly hello world program with ld fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43210936) shows a working Hello World that uses a printf from `_start`, thanks to dynamic linker hooks that let libc initialize itself without _start calling its init functions.  Also, an explanation of exactly why `execve` can return `-ENOENT` when the executable itself exists: [\`bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory\` on running executable produced by \`ld\`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33970159)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `ld` uses `/lib/ld64.so.1` as interpreter by default and you may be missing that (it can be a symlink to `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` or whatever is appropriate):

```
$ readelf -l a.out | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld64.so.1]
$ ls -l /lib/ld64.so.1
ls: cannot access /lib/ld64.so.1: No such file or directory
```

You can work around this by setting the interpreter explicitly by passing `-dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` option to your `ld` invocation:

```
$ ld -s -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 test.o -lc
$ readelf -l a.out | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
$ ./a.out
$
```

The simple rule of thumb however is to use `gcc` for linking if you need libc, it will do everything right for you. Also make sure you use `main` as entry point so that normal libc startup code has a chance of initializing. Similarly, just return from your `main` at the end and do not use `exit` syscall directly (you may use the `exit` function from libc if you really want). In general, using syscalls is not recommended.