# Linking Linux x86-64 assembly hello world program with ld fails

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm

I've been toying around with x86 64 bit assembly on linux recently and after compiling a seemingly simple program I am left scratching my head :P

Although I compile and link it throws no errors and produces a linux ELF
When i try to run it I get:

```
.:[ h4unt3r@sp3ctr4l-h0st asm ]:.
#(0)> ./hello 
bash: ./hello: No such file or directory
```

I assume its producing an invalid ELF file which is why it reports hello is not there even though it IS. Not sure why-- I'll probably keep playing around with it, just curious if this can be solved the easy way ^_^

Here is my compile / link command line:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.s -g
ld -o hello hello.o -lc
```

Here is the code:

```
section .data
    msg: db "Hello, world!",0xa,0

section .text
    extern printf
    global main

main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rdi, msg
    xor rax, rax
    call printf
    xor rax, rax

    pop rbp
    ret
```

Edit -- I do not want to use gcc :)

Comment: If it's worth anything, the file works if you remove the -lc flag and comment out the extern of printf.

Comment: How do you figure? :) Then printf is undefined symbol...

Comment: Actually I had the printf call commented out too, but what I meant to say is that if the file isn't linked against libc it works fine.

Comment: Again how do you figure? :) Are you using ld? Becasue gcc does all the proper linking for you... like incldugin libs so if you do -nostdlib or -nodefaultlibs it will fail with undefined symbol

Comment: This is the command I used to link. Probably the linking is incomplete causing the program not able to load properly. Maybe someone with better knowledge can explain. ld -o hello /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o hello.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o -lc --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am running 32-bit hardware, and can't test 64-bit stuff. I have seen this "no such file" error in 32-bit code. ld is, by default, using "/lib/ld-linux.so.1" - you can see this string in plain text in the executable. This is the file that doesn't exist (obviously "hello" is right there!). The solution is to tell ld `-I/lib/ld-linux.so.2`. I suspect that a similar solution would work for 64-bit, but I don't know what "interpreter" or "dynamic linker" you need. Try lookng in the executable for a similar string, and looking in your libs for a similar .so. You shouldn't "need" to use gcc... but gcc knows where to find this stuff! May be easier to use it. Heck of a confusing error, isn't it?

(I would expect your entrypoint to be `_start`, not `main` if you're going to do it this way. You won't be able to `ret` from this - use sys_exit or exit().)

I'm not familiar with the error nrz mentions about "symbol table 0". Surely not a deliberate change to Nasm! The Nasm developers hang out on or around http://www.nasm.us and would be delighted to hear feedback and bug reports there. (Okay, not "delighted" about bug reports, perhaps.) I'll see if I can find out anything...

FWIW, Nasm defaults to "stabs" debugging info with just the `-g` switch. To enable "dwarf" debugging info, `-F dwarf`... Supposed to work better...

Comment: Thanks! You were totally spot on :)

Answer (score 3):

First, to use `printf`, you need to do linking with `gcc` instead of `ld`:

```
gcc -o hello hello.o
```

Then, another problem may be the same I have encountered myself. I'm not sure if it's a bug or an intended change in NASM:

```
user@computer:~/code/asm$ nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -g; gcc -o hello hello.o
/usr/bin/ld: error: relocation section 9 uses unexpected symbol table 0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have resolved that problem by moving to [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net/), and doing the assembling and linking this way:

```
yasm -f elf64 hello.s -g dwarf2
gcc -o hello hello.o
```

Which produces an executable with the expected output:

```
./hello
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Well see thats the thing... I dont want to use gcc for linkage, I want to use ld :) gcc if I understand calls ld afterwards...

Comment: @h4unt3r you're right, The problem is that the standard library is missing

Comment: Well no, because the symbol printf is in stdlib and I link that explcitly with my ld flag -lc

Answer (score 2):

Modify the code a little bit to this.

```
section .data
        msg:    db "Hello, world!",0xa,0
section .text
        extern  printf
 global _start
_start:
        ; RSP already 16-byte aligned, ready for a function call.
        mov     rdi,msg           ; or better, lea rdi, [rel msg]
        xor     eax, eax          ; AL=0  - no XMM args
        call    printf

        mov     rax,60  ; use _exit syscall
        mov     rdi,0   ; exit code 0
        syscall         ; call kernel
```

and link using this to set the correct modern ld.so path, not the `ld` default which doesn't exist on modern GNU/Linux systems.

`ld hello.o -o hello -lc --dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Note that this *only* works for dynamically-linked executables.  If you link statically, you need to manually call glibc's init functions to init its data structures (like stdio buffers) before functions like `printf` will work.

Comment: `int 0x80` is not preferred with 64-bit code (it is possible to generate a Linux kernel with no 32-bit code compatibility). The preferred way is via the _SYSCALL_ instruction (careful, the system call numbers and the how data is passed differs from `int 0x80`). The use of `ret` is not an issue if linking with the _C_ runtime as `main` is a function and there is a return address on the stack that goes back to the _C_ runtime function that called it (one just has to ensure they follow the rules of which registers are caller/callee saved)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Modified to syscall based on your input. Thanks!