# Manually linked file doesn't exist when trying to run it, but does otherwise

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, nasm, ld

I'm messing around with some assembler and trying to assemble it with nasm and link it with ld on my ubuntu machine. This is my code

```
EXTERN puts

SECTION .data
hello: db "Hello world!\0"

SECTION .text

global _start
_start:
    ; puts(hello)
    mov rdi, dword hello
    call puts

    ; exit(0)
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov eax, 60
    syscall
```

When I compile it with

```bash
nasm helloworld.asm
ld -lc -o helloworld helloworld.o
```

both commands return exit status 0 and the file exists. But when I try to run the file, it suddenly doesn't exist anymore, or at least that's what my shell is telling me.

```bash
$ ls helloworld -alh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user group 14K Okt 28 10:44 helloworld
$ ./helloworld
sh: 4: ./helloworld: not found
$ file helloworld
helloworld: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld64.so.1, not stripped
```

I have tried sh, bash and zsh. I also tried to run with with exec. When I open it with gdb I can `disassemble _start` and it shows the correct instructions, but when I `run` it just says that the file doesn't exist again. When I load the file in cutter it shows the correct disassembly, but when I try to run it with the debugger it just hangs.

Furthermore when I just returned 0 and didn't have the puts in there, I linked without the `-lc` flag and then everything worked as expected.

What's going on?

Comment: The executable exists but its dynamic linker (`/lib/ld64.so.1`) probably doesn't. Either you make a symbolic link to make the hardcoded path work or you use `--dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` or whatever works in your distribution (you can use `file` on any working x64 binary to find out). I don't know why `ld` uses such a wrong path by default or why there is no symbolic link to make it work. It seems link distributions make `ld` not working by default (despite what the manual says).

Comment: @MargaretBloom thank you. if you answer with that, I shall accept it. Although I don't understand why that happens still.

Comment: If the linked duplicate doesn't cover everything, see also [Can't run executable linked with libc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13989396) and the Q&As linked in a comment there.